# Как получить размер строк и столбцов в excel xlrd python

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd

Как с помощью xlrd узнать размер строк и столбцов. Есть метод sheet.computed_column_width(1) - он определяет ширину колонки под индексом 1, но неправильно. Как получить данные для строк

Comment: что вы понимаете под `размером строк и столбцов`? В чем вы их хотите измерять? Измерять конкретные строки и столбцы по индексу или найти максимальный размер?

Comment: Надо получить высоту и ширину строк и столбцов по индексу. В excel эти значения в дюймах, мне все равно в какой системе счисления я получу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Rowinfo) можно получить информацию о строках и столбцах:

- высота строки будет в твипах (1/20 точки);
- ширина столбца будет в единицах 1/256 от ширины нулевого символа.

Пример кода, выводящего информацию о высоте строк и ширине столбцов:

```
import xlrd

rb = xlrd.open_workbook("style2003.xls", formatting_info=True) 
sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
w = sheet.computed_column_width(0)

for i, row in sheet.rowinfo_map.items():
    print("row {0} has {1} twip height".format(i, row.height))

for i, col in sheet.colinfo_map.items():
    print("column {0} has {1} width".format(i, col.width))
```